# Coin regeneration help!

Tags: coin-dozer

I'm playing coin dozer. I'm on level 110. I have 360 something coins. And my regeneration level is 90, but my coins won't stop regenerating. How do I stop this!?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have 7+ of each yoyo prize? If you do, you will have no regent limit. If you want to stop this, sell your prizes until at least 1 type has 6 or less. Your coins will stop regenerating at 90.